# How to add each contents' value separately and add them all?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'd like to calculate values in form. Each total from each table with the class of category needs to be filled in the textbox named subtotal. Then, each values of input named subtotal needs to be added and filled in the textbox named total.
However, I am totally stack, then, can not figure out. Please help.

I've tried to loop each table to calculate but didn't work.

```js
function calc() {
  price = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.myform.length - 1; i++) {
    if (document.myform.elements[i].checked) {
      price += eval(document.myform.elements[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.myform.subtotal.value = price;
  var sumup = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < subtotal.length; i++) {
    sumup += eval(subtotal[i].value);
  }
  document.myform.total.value = sumup;
  document.myform.discount30.value = sumup * .7;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <table class="category">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="yyy" onClick="calc()">Yes</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="radio" name="zzz" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="radio" name="zzz" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
        </ul>
        <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="yyy" onClick="calc()">No</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>amount：<input type="text" name="subtotal">yen</label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="category">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="xxx" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="yyy" onClick="calc()">Yes</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="radio" name="zzz" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="radio" name="zzz" value="500" onClick="calc()">500</label></li>
        </ul>
        <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="yyy" onClick="calc()">No</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>amount：<input type="text" name="subtotal">yen</label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>



  <table class="output">
    <tr>
      <td><label>total：<input type="text" name="total">yen</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>30% discount：<input type="text" name="discount30">yen</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: I think the first thing any developer needs to learn is how to debug. Part of that is reading error messages in the console. In this case, when I click a checkbox, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: subtotal is not defined`. Looking at your code, you start using `subtotal` (in the `for` loop, `subtotal.length`) without ever defining it.

Comment: using eval() is not a good idea... why are you not using parseFloat or parseInt, or Number?

Comment: I'm also going to highly recommend to use any other number interpreting option besides eval such as `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number`, etc. You can directly switch `eval` here for `Number`, as well.